# OpenNI driver wont start sometimes

Tags: ros, openni-node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have problem with the OpenNI driver `openni_node`. Sometime it dies with the following error:

```
$ rosrun openni_camera openni_node _device_id:=1@0
[ INFO] [1365593984.497957554]: Initializing nodelet with 4 worker threads.
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'openni_wrapper::OpenNIException'
  what():  unsigned int openni_wrapper::OpenNIDriver::updateDeviceList() @ /tmp/buildd/ros-fuerte-openni-camera-1.8.6/debian/ros-fuerte-openni-camera/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/openni_camera/src/openni_driver.cpp @ 125 : enumerating image nodes failed. Reason: One or more of the following nodes could not be enumerated:

Image: PrimeSense/SensorV2/5.1.2.1: Failed to set USB interface!

Aborted
```

I have changed the nodelet to node and  add `respam="true"` in the `openni.launch`, so eventually it will start normally. But that doesn't fix the error.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60396/openni-driver-wont-start-sometimes/) by [liborw](https://answers.ros.org/users/2302/liborw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 801 on 2013-04-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In my experience, there can be several different reasons why the Kinect would not start.  First would be that there are still processes running that did not shutdown properly.  Try using a command like `ps aux |grep Xn` to see if there are any processes running that may prevent a startup.  If so, use `kill -9 [PID]` to kill them.  (I don't think this is your problem, but I'm putting it here for completeness.)

Sometimes I experience problems with the Linux USB hotplugging module.  Unplugging the Kinect from the computer and then running the command `sudo service udev reload` will often allow the Kinect to start.  I have had to run this command so many times that I have an alias bound for it.

Recently on one of the computers in our lab (none of the others), we were getting the same error that you were when we tried to launch the Kinect.  Looking at `dmesg` revealed that `ehci_hcd` kernel support was having fatal errors.  In newer versions of linux kernels, this is not a module, but rather part of the main kernel.  So I wrote a bash script that looks like

```
echo -n "0000:00:1a.0" | tee /sys/bus/pci/drivers/ehci_hcd/unbind
echo -n "0000:00:1d.0" | tee /sys/bus/pci/drivers/ehci_hcd/unbind
echo -n "0000:00:1a.0" | tee /sys/bus/pci/drivers/ehci_hcd/bind
echo -n "0000:00:1d.0" | tee /sys/bus/pci/drivers/ehci_hcd/bind
```

gave it executable permissions, and put it on the `PATH`.  When we were getting your error, this script fixed the problem.  Note that your device numbers (xxxx:xx:xx.x) may be slightly different.  I think you can find your device numbers in `/sys/bus/usb/devices/`.  You'll need to use `sudo` on the script.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2013-04-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chao](https://answers.ros.org/users/9591/chao/) on 2013-12-29**:
hi, i tried to use the method you teach. it worked last time, but for this time, i kept getting the error message
chao      2869  0.0  0.0  13592   940 pts/0    S+   14:17   0:00 grep --color=auto Xn
chao@chao-LIFEBOOK-AH532:~$ kill -9 2869
bash: kill: (2869) - No such process
do you know what's wrong with this?

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2013-12-31**:
Your message is a little hard to read, but it seems like you are misinterpreting the output of `ps` and `grep`.  In your example, the PID 2869 is the PID of the grep process that was searching for the XnSensorServer process.  You cannot kill it because it has already completed.

**Comment by [chao](https://answers.ros.org/users/9591/chao/) on 2013-12-31**:
My apologies, i did try to use 'enter' to make a new line. Guess it doesn't work here. Yea, i realized that i can't kill it because the process doesn't exist in the first place. Have solved my problem by reinstall openni packages. Anyway, thanks a lot :) Happy new year!!

**Comment by [simbaforrest](https://answers.ros.org/users/15236/simbaforrest/) on 2014-04-27**:
Thank you for the answer! I was using an Asus Xtion Pro and suddenly it won't connect anymore. I typed "lsusb -v | grep PrimeSense" and it got stuck there. So I tried your commands: "sudo service udev reload" and it worked again!